# В якому контексті правильно вживати "одягати", "надівати", "надягати"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова, префікс

Ми часто чуємо від мами "*одягни* шапку". Завжди думала, що так казати правильно. Але недавно наткнулась на таку [інформацію](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/odyahaty-nadivaty-uzuvaty-obuvaty). А як щодо слова *надягати*? В якому контексті правильно вживати *"одягати", "надівати", "надягати"?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Значення слів

#### 1. [Одягати](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8):

1. у що і без додатка. Покривати одягом кого-небудь.

   // у що, перен. Надавати чому-небудь певної форми, втілювати в якісь образи і т. ін.

   // Добирати для кого-небудь відповідний до певної нагоди одяг; відповідно наряджати кого-небудь.

   // Покривати **себе** чим-небудь з одягу. Почав [Дмитро] одягати кожушок (Стельмах, II, 1962, 383); Джмелик бере із лави штани, спокійно одягає їх, твердо стоячи на одній нозі (Тют., Вир, 1964, 191).
2. Приладнувати, закріплювати щось на кому-, чому-небудь, начіплювати щось на кого-, що-небудь.
3. розм. Забезпечувати одягом кого-небудь.
4. чим, у що, перен. Покривати поверхню чого-небудь.

Отже, "одягати" несе в собі значення дії, що її направляють як на себе, так і на кого-, що-небудь.

#### 2. [Надівати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=54251&page=1727):

1. Одягати на **себе** або на когось одяг, взуття.
2. Приладжувати, прикріплювати щось на кому-, чому-небудь, до кого-, чого-небудь.
3. Щільно вставляти, закріплювати, насаджувати на що-небудь.

Отже, надівати можна щось і на себе, і на когось іншого.

#### 3. [Надягати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=54636&page=1741):

1. Натягувати, насувати, накладати і т. ін. одяг на кого-, що-небудь.

   // **Використовувати, носити** який-небудь одяг.
2. Приладновувати, прикріплювати на чому-небудь.

Зі словом "надягати" так само, як зі словом "надівати". Можна і на себе, і на когось/щось інше щось "надягти".

### Висновки

Тобто всі три слова можна використовувати як на позначення вдягання себе, так і на позначення вдягання когось чи чогось.

Comment: Зазначу, шчо СУМ вже маье тутешні слова на Н.

Comment: @stegetsj наче нічого не змінилось. До речі, якщо в якомусь питанні бачите від мене посилання на СУМ-11, а вже є схожа стаття на СУМ-20 - дозволяю заздалегідь змінювати посилання. І позначати мене.